# Рандомная строка

Tags: python

Есть строка, надо "перепутать" все её символы (именно перепутать, не брать рандомные, без потери символов). Как это сделать?

Comment: А чем "перепутать" отличается от последовательной выборки из исходной строки случайных символов без повторений? Ну вот была строк "АБВГДЕ". Получили строку "ГАБЕВД". Она "перепутна" или "случайно выбрана"?

Comment: @passant перепутать символы которые есть в строке, т.е. не использовать символы, которых в ней нет, и в то же время использовать все, которые есть, без остатка

Comment: @whizz169 - я и спросил - пример выше это "перепутать" или "выбрать без потери символов"?

Answer (score 9):

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668312/shuffle-string-in-python)

```
import random
l = list(s)
random.shuffle(l)
result = ''.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install python-string-utils
```

```
import string_utils
print(string_utils.shuffle("random_string"))
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string_utils'` :) Если это не "из коробки", то укажите как установить / где достать

Comment: @gil9red поправил :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import random

def shuffle(s):
    origin = list(s)
    return ''.join([origin.pop(random.randint(0, len(origin) - 1)) for _ in range(len(s))])

print(shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
# kctnbqydgrwsoxpveflahijmuz
```

Comment: Проще было дописать пример с `shuffle`: `l = list(s)` `random.shuffle(l)`
`return ''.join(l)` :)